# column group not displayed in profile

Tags: wordpress, profile, groups

I created a new profile that includes the field group, but when I do an advanced search using this profile, the column group is not displayed. 
Why ?
I need a list with name, group membership.

If I put the group as public, then I see it, but not out in the report. I can not have a report with name and group. I have to do a custom field?

Thanks.
Marco Mapelli